# Сигналы ячейки QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, tableview, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

мне хотелось бы понять, какие сигналы испускают ячейки `QTableView` в состоянии редактирования? Хочу, чтобы каждая новая буква в ячейке в прямом времени обновляла данные в моём `lineEdit`. Если таких сигналов нет, то как можно такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого необходимо сделать собственный делегат отображения (детали реализации опущу):

```
class MyDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate {
    ...

signals:
    void cellValueChanged(const QModelIndex& index, const QString& value);

public:
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override) {
        if (!index.isValid()) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        MyLineEdit* lineEdit = new MyLineEdit(parent);
        lineEdit.setModelIndex(index);
        lineEdit.setGeometry(option.rect());
        connect(lineEdit, &MyLineEdit::valueChanged, this, &MyDelegate::cellValueChanged);
        return lineEdit;
    }
}
```

`MyLineEdit` (наследуется от QLineEdit) нужен для хранения текущего редактируемого `QModelIndex` и формирования "удобного" сигнала передачи измененного введенного значения:

```
class MyLineEdit: public QLineEdit {
    //...
signals:
    void valueChanged(const QModelIndex& index, const QString& value);
public:
    MyLineEdit(QWidget* parent = nullptr): QLineEdit(parent) {
        connect(this, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [&](const QString& value) {
            emit valueChanged(index, value);
        }
    }
    void setModelIndex(const QModelIndex& index) {
        this->index = index;
    }
private:
    QModelIndex index;
}
```

Далее, например в конструкторе объекта главного окна, объект делегата устанавливается в объект таблицы:

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow {
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr): 
        QMainWindow(parent) {
        MyDelegate* delegate = new MyDelegate();

        // Подключаем слушатель изменения значений в ячейках таблицы
        connect(delegate, &MyDelegate::cellValueChanged, [&](const QModelIndex& index, const QString& value) {
            qDebug() << index << value;
        });
        ui->tableView->setItemDelegate(delegate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Но я видимо не до конца понимаю роль `MyLineEdit`. Где мы конкретно его используем в `MainWindow`?

Comment: @resusfactor_228 в делегате таблицы в `createEditor`.  Причём тут `MainWindow`?

Comment: @resusfactor_228 немного уточнил код, так понятнее?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin спасибо, но я понимал, что это все происходит в `MainWindow`, проблема видимо в моих знаниях о делегатах)